# How to save form data to different models with one-to-one relationship in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a user controller and a user model. In my user table I have limited fields. But now I want to create separate tables for user bank info and user personal info and save through the one form only. How is it possible, I am sure their must be something for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how [nested_forms works](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) along with the [view helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Basically you add this in your user class :

```
class User < AR
  has_one :profile
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :adress
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :profile_attributes, address_attributes #etc
end
```

and in you form :

```
=form_for @user do |user_form|
  = user_form.text_field :name
  = user_form.field_for :profile do |profile_form|
    =profile_form.text_field :bank_name
  = user_form.field_for :address do |address_form|
    =address_form.text_field :city
```

Comment: can i need to use "attribute => :accessible" method with it

Comment: Thanks a lot charlysisto it work for two models, but i have to put data i multiple tables for which it look's problematic.Is their any their solution

Comment: hi ravindra, look at my updated answer to see how to add more

Comment: i did it earlier and this trick  works but doesn't show other models fields.i had tried it two day's ago.Thanks for support

Comment: "but doesn't show other models fields" ??? I don't understand, in what circumstances ?

Comment: Sorry...charlysisto, One good news ,i have solved that problem.But now a new one , in every model i have some type of date field for which i used date picker.The problem is that in my nested form datepicker doesn't populate the calender