# Rails 4 Nested Form with One to One Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models with a one to one relationship, User and Author.

I have two issues: the author instance isn't saving, and user.name isn't saving (although other attributes are).  I think it is a permission error because the logs say:

`Unpermitted parameters: name, authors`

I was trying to follow this: [How to save form data to different models with one-to-one relationship in rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660023/how-to-save-form-data-to-different-models-with-one-to-one-relationship-in-rails)

User.rb

```
has_one :author
accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
```

Author.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

authors#new

```
 <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :author do |author_form| %>
        <%= author_form.input :bio %>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Users_Controller

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :image,
  author_attributes: [:id, :bio,])
end
```

Comment: hey, did you try what I've suggested?

Comment: yes, sorry, it didn't work.  still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Devise gem and found the solution to be adding this code to the Application Controller:

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, author_attributes: [:id, :bio]) }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

User controller should look like this:-

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_author
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to success_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, author_attributes: [:id, :bio])
end
```

Users#new

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :author do |author_form| %>
        <%= author_form.input :bio %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work.  I don't get the params error, but it doesn't seem to work.  I use the `Devise` gem and the logs show this error `'Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected'.`

Comment: Add this :- prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [:action1, :action2] in controller